# How the Mode Formula in R works...?

Tags: r, mode

I found this formula can be used for R to find the MODE for any column in a Dataset, ho does it work...??

```r
names(sort(-table(mtcars$wt)))[1]
```

it can be used to find the MODE for wt colimn.

I need to understand this formula.

Comment: Note that that expression has the problem that it returns a character result.  This one does not: `mtcars$wt[which.max(ave(mtcars$wt, mtcars$wt, FUN = length))]`

Answer (score 2):

To learn what the whole expression does, you should step through each component.

- `table` tabulates (counts) the occurrences for each unique value within `$wt`:

  ```r
  table(mtcars$wt)
  # 1.513 1.615 1.835 1.935  2.14   2.2  2.32 2.465  2.62  2.77  2.78 2.875  3.15  3.17  3.19 3.215 3.435  3.44  3.46 
  #     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     3     1 
  #  3.52  3.57  3.73  3.78  3.84 3.845  4.07  5.25 5.345 5.424 
  #     1     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  ```

  Note that the original "value" of `$wt` is stored as the names within the returned vector.
- `sort(-table(.))` then brings the most-frequent value to the front (left) and least-frequent value to the back (right).

  ```r
  sort(-table(mtcars$wt))
  #  3.44  3.57 1.513 1.615 1.835 1.935  2.14   2.2  2.32 2.465  2.62  2.77  2.78 2.875  3.15  3.17  3.19 3.215 3.435 
  #    -3    -2    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1 
  #  3.46  3.52  3.73  3.78  3.84 3.845  4.07  5.25 5.345 5.424 
  #    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  ```

  Sorting on the negative of it is equivalent to `sort(table(.), decreasing=TRUE)`.
- `names(..)` will return the original `wt` values from this vector, sorted in the decreasing order of their counts. Adding `[1]` to that returns only the first of the name.

Long-story-short: this returns the first value within `mtcars$wt` that occurs the most. FYI, if there are multiple values with the same count, this code will not indicate that condition.